# HTML5/CSS3 Rotating 3D Cube

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have logo like below ..

[image]

In that there is 3D cube with different color faces. I need to make that cube rotate using HTML5/CSS3. Also it should work on all modern browsers.

I found sample code with 3d cube. It works well on Chrome, Firefox and IE. http://html5example.net/entry/html5-canvas/html5-canvas-pre3d-rotating-cube.

Now i need to set different color for each face in the cube, Make it auto rotating and place it on top of image (logo text).

How to do it ?

In the sample code with pre3d same color is used for whole cube.

```
renderer.fill_rgba = new Pre3d.RGBA(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: You could use an animated `gif` rather than HTML5/CSS. Draw your cube and light it in a free application like `blender`, animate and save.

Comment: Otherwise the example that you pointed to uses the [`pre3d`](https://github.com/deanm/pre3d) library.

Comment: @Xotic750 i also was thinking about that. but sharpness and quality wont be good right ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. http://blog.3dstuffmaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/5-cube-3d-animated-gif-images1.gif

Answer (score 2):

This one should be helpful for you

http://codepen.io/cliffpyles/pen/LHlqa

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html

Take a look this inspiring tutorial which will be very helpful for you.

**http://davidwalsh.name/css-cube**

Comment: Thanks. How can i make the box rote bit down ? like this http://i.imgur.com/IxBRUT3.png

Comment: I think you can try with `transform:translateY(50px);`

Comment: 3D CSS transforms don't appear widely supported yet, works in FFv27 but not in Chromium v27. Even as 2D it didn't work on a recent version of Opera that I tried. I guess it depends on what the OP means by "should work on all modern browsers"

Comment: What jsFiddle? I followed your links.

Comment: @Xotic750 you can show your effort through http://jsfiddle.net/ in that way I can give you good instruction on the basis of so far works

Comment: @Xotic750 Transorm support all the latest browser including opera http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms

Comment: Why should I provide a jsFiddle when the links you provided are all that are required for testing? When I visit with Chromium v27 (which is a modern browser, the latest package available on my OS) then the 3D CSS is not supported and I see `Sorry, your browser does not support CSS 3D transforms. Try viewing this page in Safari, Chrome, Firefox Aurora, or on an iOS device.` And from your latest link it shows that IE10 and IE11 are only partially supported, and they are also modern browsers, are they not?

Comment: The released package of Chromium v27 stable was 11-Jun-2013, less than a year old.

Comment: The released package of Opera which is v16 was 7-Aug-2013

Comment: FireFox v26 was Mozilla's first release that supports it and that was 10-Dec-2013 Only 3 months ago.

Comment: Not everyone can (or is allowed to) live on the "bleeding edge", but that's not my definition of a modern browser. And all of those CSS methods are still working drafts, as stated in the link that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at here:
[Rotating Cube](http://codepen.io/rikardlegge/pen/aprxJ)

Or search for other examples on that site!!

Comment: Thanks. I'll check. Given cube doesn't work on IE 11

Comment: Probably it is because of the -ms-* css prefix required by IE. Maybe these css3 properties require this prefix.
Try to add them and check it.

Answer (score 1):

Though not exactly `CSS3` but There is a Javascript plugin named `three.js`. You can try it once. Link is given below.

1. [three.js](http://threejs.org/examples/)
2. [Another example of `three.js`](http://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/427c1ffc346ed9286fda)